# CSS problem: <li> will shift when I fill it with content

Tags: css, list

Hej there,

I fail to create a simple list made up of list items that have background images and show some info when you click/tap on them. I can't figure out what's wrong, maybe someone can help me.

So I got this unordered list within an article:

```
<article>
    <h2>Aktivitäten am Freitagnachmittag/-abend</h2>
       <ul class="programList">
          <li id="wassersport">
            <h1 id="wassersportHeader">Wassersport</h1>
            <p id="wassersportInfo">Here be infotext</p>
          </li>
          <li id="lasertag"> 
            <h1 id="lasertagHeader">Lasertag</h1> 
            <p id="lasertagInfo">Here be infotext</p>
          </li>
          <li id="flusssauna"> 
            <h1 id="flusssaunaHeader">Flußsauna</h1>
            <p id="flusssaunaInfo">Here be infotext</p>
          </li>          
      </ul>
</article>
```

Then I add the following CSS:

```
article {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

article h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 3rem;
}

article h2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

article p {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

article ul {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    list-style-position: inside;
}

.programList {
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.programList li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 350px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#wassersportInfo {
    display: none;
}

#flusssaunaInfo {
    display: none;
}

#lasertagInfo {
    display: none;
}
```

The list shows nicely - I have three images with overlayed headers that show up next to or above each other, depending on the screen size. On my screen, they show in one row.

However when I set one of the p (say, #wassersportInfo) to `display: block;` (manually or via JS), so that the infotext appears within the list item element, then suddenly the other list items shift down. The list items with the now visible p in it still has the same distance to the h2 above the list, but the others are displayed with some offset from the top.

I suspected it had something to do with the bottom margins I gave h1 and p elements within article elements, so I set the bottom margins of the h1 and p elements within the list items to zero by doing this:

```
.programList h1 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.programList p {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

That did something, but not all the way, there is still some offset for the list items where the display properties of the p are set to none. Anyway, I don't understand why a list item with a specified height and width shifts its (or other list items') position when you put something in it.

The problem disappears altogether when the screen width is so small that the list items are displayed above each other, but that's of course not what I want for bigger screens.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your problem correctly but if I'm wrong please correct me.

You want to have a list of items with a hidden information. After the user clicks on the item the hidden text will pop.

For this you have few option:

1. You can try using Boostrap's accordions. Customize the header as you wish and upon clicking one you will get the result you want.
2. If you want a more "custom" approach you can either use a JS library or JS itself. As a demonstration I will help you with the principle in the following code:

```js
function toggleText(element){
    var p = document.querySelectorAll("p");
    [].forEach.call(p, function(el) {
        if(el.classList.contains("active-element"))
            el.classList.remove("active-element");
    });

  element.querySelector('p').classList.toggle("active-element");
}
```

```css
article {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
}

article h1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 3rem;
}

article h2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

article p {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

article ul {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    list-style-position: inside;
}

.programList {
    list-style-position: inside;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.programList li {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 350px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#wassersportInfo {
    display: none;
}

#flusssaunaInfo {
    display: none;
}

#lasertagInfo {
    display: none;
}

.active-element{
display:block!important;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <h2>Aktivitäten am Freitagnachmittag/-abend</h2>
       <ul class="programList">
          <li id="wassersport" onclick="toggleText(this)">
            <h1 id="wassersportHeader">Wassersport</h1>
            <p id="wassersportInfo">Here be infotext</p>
          </li>
          <li id="lasertag" onclick="toggleText(this)"> 
            <h1 id="lasertagHeader" >Lasertag</h1> 
            <p id="lasertagInfo">Here be infotext</p>
          </li>
          <li id="flusssauna" onclick="toggleText(this)"> 
            <h1 id="flusssaunaHeader" >Flußsauna</h1>
            <p id="flusssaunaInfo">Here be infotext</p>
          </li>          
      </ul>
</article>
```

Please let me know if this covers your question.